# How should dynamically defined instance attributes be used with type hints/linting?

Tags: python, inheritance, static-analysis, type-hinting

Consider the following code, where my class `Child` inherits from `Parent` (a class that comes from a third-party package, over which I have no control). `Parent` has a built-in method `set_attributes`, which is used to add arbitrary attributes to an instance:

```
# third-party code, I can't modify this
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, a: str) -> None:
        self.a = a

    def set_attributes(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)


# my code, I can modify this
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a: str, b: int, c: float) -> None:
        super().__init__(a=a)
        self.set_attributes(b=b, c=c)

    def show_attributes(self):
        print(self.a)
        print(self.b)
        print(self.c)
```

This works fine, but any linter will give me a warning on the `show_attributes` method, telling me that `self.b` and `self.c` do not exist (because they're defined at runtime, when the line `self.set_attributes(b=b, c=c)` is executed).

One way to overcome this limitation is to define a placeholder for the attributes in `Child.__init__`:

```
from typing import Optional

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a: str, b: int, c: float) -> None:
        super().__init__(a=a)
        self.b: Optional[int] = None
        self.c: Optional[float] = None
        self.set_attributes(b=b, c=c)
```

...but the issue now is that `self.b` and `self.c` aren't *really* supposed to be `None` values - it's just a placeholder. I don't want my linter to consider the possibility that these values could be `None` for the rest of my code, because they shouldn't be.

Other alternatives I've thought about are:

- Remove `Optional` from the type hint - now the linter warns me that `self.b` and `self.c` should not be `None`:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a: str, b: int, c: float) -> None:
        super().__init__(a=a)
        self.b: int = None
        self.c: float = None
        self.set_attributes(b=b, c=c)
```

- Use a default value of the proper type: this works, but feels hacky and verbose (I feel like this will bite me back later):

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a: str, b: int, c: float) -> None:
        super().__init__(a=a)
        self.b: int = 0
        self.c: float = 0.0
        self.set_attributes(b=b, c=c)
```

- type hint the attributes, but do not give them a placeholder value: this looks good, but the linter still believes these attributes do not exist, even after executing the `set_attributes` method:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a: str, b: int, c: float) -> None:
        super().__init__(a=a)
        self.b: int
        self.c: float
        self.set_attributes(b=b, c=c)
```

None of these solutions are very satisfying to me. Also, none of these solutions work if I decide to maintain the flexibility of `set_attributes` by adding `**kwargs` to `Child.__init__`, i.e.:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a: str, b: int, c: float, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(a=a)
        self.b: int
        self.c: float
        self.set_attributes(b=b, c=c, **kwargs)
```

Is there any better way to work around this, or is it just a limitation I have to get used to?

Comment: dynamically defined attributes are inherently at odds with nominal typing.

Comment: @pavel I don't see any ambiguity, they are using `Optional[int]` and `Optional[float]` which would be the pretty idiomatic way of tpying `Union[None, int]` and `Union[None, float]`.